# Volume of tanks and speed of water flow

Tags: volume

An open rectangular tank of depth $2.4$m has a horizontal base of length $3.8$ m and breadth $2.1$m.

A solid metal cylinder of volume $0.865m^3$ rests with its curbed surface on  base in the tank .

$6400$ litres of water is poured into the tank at rate of $900 cm^3/s$

Calculate how many hours and minutes it takes for all the water to be poured in , giving answer to nearest minute.

My working is -

Vol of tank = $2.4 \times 3.8 \times 2.1 = 19.152m^3$

After here I'm not too sure how to carry on

Answer (score 0):

There is just a bunch of extraneous information to confuse you. The time is just the volume divided by the rate:
$$6400\,L\times\frac{1000\,cm^3}{L}\times\frac{1\,s}{900\,cm^3}\approx7111.1\,s=1:58:31.1$$
or $1$ hour, $59$ minutes to nearest minute.

Comment: Why do i have to X 1000cm^3 ?

Comment: 6400 litres is the same as 6400 cm^3 right

Comment: Jeez, if I could sell you $1\,cm^3$ of beer for the price of $1\,L$ :)